# Cannot enable org-roam mode - No EmacSQL SQLite binary avaiable

Tags: org-mode, sqlite

I've installed org-roam (Windows 10, 26.3 x86_64-w64-mingw32) but when I try to call org-roam... then Emacs show:

```
Loading d:/MEGAsync/Emacs/config/init.el (source)...done
Could not find C compiler, skipping SQLite build
Org-roam initialization: (error "No EmacSQL SQLite binary available, aborting")
Could not find C compiler, skipping SQLite build
emacsql-sqlite-ensure-binary: No EmacSQL SQLite binary available, aborting
```

Please help :-)

Comment: I had a similar problem on Mac OS and search led me here. I upgraded Emacs to 27.2-3 from https://emacsformacosx.com/ and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error originates from https://github.com/skeeto/emacsql/blob/master/emacsql-sqlite.el which checks whether there's a binary created from a previous compilation, then attempts to build it on your system. You haven't built one yet and don't have a toolchain set up, so it errors out early.

https://github.com/skeeto/emacsql/issues/55#issuecomment-515704368 gives a short introduction into the many possible ways of compiling C programs on Windows. I second the recommendation of setting up a mingw-w64 environment, be it with or without msys2.

Comment: That was exactly what I'm looking for - thank You!

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by doing the following steps:

1. Install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) package manager
2. Install `emacs`, `sqlite`, `mingw` and `msys2` using `chocolatey`

```
choco install emacs sqlite msys2 mingw -y
```

3. Open your configuration file or your `init.el` file in your `.emacs.d` directory and copy paste the following code and save it. For more details, visit [org-roam user manual](https://www.orgroam.com/manual.html#Introduction)

```
(use-package org-roam :ensure t)
```

4. Open `emacs` to force it to download the `org-roam` packages
5. Open `msys2` and execute the following commands (These steps may not be necessary, however it is recommended based on the [MSYS2 Website](https://www.msys2.org/)):

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -Su
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

6. Open `msys2` and execute the following command:

```
pacman -S gcc
```

7. While still inside `msys2`, navigate to your downloaded `emacs-sqlite` package located in your `.emacs.d`. In my case, it is located here: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\elpa\emacsql-sqlite-20190727.1710\sqlite`. Therefore, the command was:

```
cd C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/emacsql-sqlite-20190727.1710/sqlite
```

if you're using **Spacemacs**, then sqlite will be in a different folder like:

```
C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/27.2/develop/emacsql-sqlite-20190727.1710
```

8. In your `emacsql-sqlite/sqlite` directory, you should have these four files:

- emacsql.c
- Makefile
- sqlite3.c
- sqlite3.h

9. While inside `emacsql-sqlite/sqlite` directory, execute the following command:

```
make emacsql-sqlite CC=gcc LDLIBS=
```

10. Now you should have an additional file called `emacsql-sqlite.exe`.
11. Lastly, just restart your `emacs` and you are good to go.

Hope this help anybody in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Naim, this helped in installation.  But I'm not able to use org-roam, I'm receiving a `Selecting Deleted buffer` error. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: along with these steps, I also had to install **mingw** to get it to work in my windows PC. After step 2, you need to install mingw using `choco install mingw`

Comment: Thank you! You recipe worked as you say for Emacs 28 and org-roam Melpa version 20221203.1750.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue, and a similar one (`org-roam cannot find executable sqlite3`) by downloading manually the binary of [SQLite for Windows](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

Download, unzip, and put the executable at a location known by Windows PATH (or set its location in the PATH variable, in the Environment Variables). Reload Emacs, and it works!

Comment: can you confirm if you've downloaded the "sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000.zip". Also can you add the location of "`Windows PATH`" in your case. I tried placing the sqlite3.exe file in `.emacs.d` folder, but it didn't work!!