# org-roam (new install) error "Selecting Deleted Buffer"

Tags: org-roam

I'm fairly new to Emacs and Org-Roam and struggled for few days to get Org-roam installed on my Windows 10 PC. But I successfully got it installed after following [these steps](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68115/36093).
Note that I installed Emacs from scratch and have not used org-roam till now.

I verified the org-roam installed by checking the variable `org-roam--sqlite-available-p` (Its value is t).

But when I use `org-roam-node-find` to create a new org-roam node I'm getting an error: `Selecting Deleted Buffer`.

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything, but here is my init.el configuration:

```
;; Packages
(require 'package)                   ; Bring in to the environment all package management functions
;; A list of package repositories
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("org"   . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                         ("elpa"  . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)                 ; Initializes the package system and prepares it to be used
(unless package-archive-contents     ; Unless a package archive already exists,
  (package-refresh-contents))        ; Refresh package contents so that Emacs knows which packages to load

;; Initialize use-package on non-linux platforms
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)        ; Unless "use-package" is installed, install "use-package"
  (package-install 'use-package))
(require 'use-package)                            ; Once it's installed, we load it using require

(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(setq package-check-signature nil)

(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages '(org-roam use-package org-roam-bibtex)))
(custom-set-faces
 )

(require 'org)
(use-package org-roam 
    :ensure t
    :bind (("C-c n l" . org-roam-buffer-toggle)
           ("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
           ("C-c n i" . org-roam-node-insert))
    :config
    (org-roam-setup))
```

Comment: Do you need to show all of your init file here? Bisect the file, to find the culprit. Then ask your question about that relevant portion (only). Thx.

Comment: I honestly don't know what the issue is. And this is the default configuration with additional hot keys at the end for org-roam. As far as I remember, there's nothing else that I added. But I removed the comments to make it more readable without scroll.

Comment: hi this is work for me [https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=60872#11](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=60872#11) after you have to delete emacsql-sqlite.elc file

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem and resolved it by deleting the `~/.emacs.d/org-roam.db` file and then running `org-roam-db-sync`.

So whatever the analogue to the home directory or Emacs home directory is, go there, delete the org-roam.db file, and then inside of emacs hit `M-x` and type `org-roam-db-sync` and that might fix this for you.