# Emacs will not compile sqlite binary and will not run compiled sqlite binary

Tags: compilation, org-roam, sqlite

I am running emacs 28.2 on windows 10, trying to start using the `org-roam` package which requires `emacsql-sqlite`. I have installed msys2 and used it to install gcc following the instructions [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68115) as well as adding the folder containing the gcc executable to my `PATH`. Emacs will not compile the binary on its own, instead giving this error when I try to run an org-roam command: `Error (use-package): org-roam/:config: No EmacSQL SQLite binary available: (Cannot compile EmacSQL SQLite binary: "")`.

I continued following the linked instructions to manually compile it. This resulted in the following error when attempting to use org-roam: `Error (use-package): org-roam/:config: Process emacsql-sqlite not running`. Very strangely, having a compiled emacsql-sqlite binary stop `magit` from working with the same error even though it didn't have any issues with no access to the binary.

I have no idea how to move forward with this and would appreciate any advice.